# Bounding selection box in gazebo does not overlay with visual links

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Bounding selection box in gazebo does not overlay with visual links when selecting a link in the worlds model tab for the robot model. In this case the model in the  inverse pendulum tutorial that is a urdf file.  I am running Hydro with Gazebo 1.9.  I also have the same problem in a mobil robot model sdf file I converted to urdf. in the case of the pendulum once gravity moves it the selection box does not track with it. In the model robot car tutorial the wheel selections do not line up with the links but do when it is a sdf file.

[C:\fakepath\Screenshot of selection box.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13767482949311123.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4156/bounding-selection-box-in-gazebo-does-not-overlay-with-visual-links./) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/709/fix-mouse-picking-for-cases-where-visuals/diff) to track this problem.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0